# Create instance of class with internal / private constructor in GOSU language

Tags: java, guidewire

I want to create an instance of class with only one `internal` constructor for unit-tests purpose. I am running Guidewire version 10.
Getting error on string with `.newInstance` call:

```
    var s3ServiceCtor = InternalBucketS3Service.getClass().getDeclaredConstructors().first()
    s3ServiceCtor.setAccessible(true)
    var newInstanceResult = s3ServiceCtor.newInstance({_testClaim}.toArray())
    return newInstanceResult as S3Service
```

Here is a class I want to create:

```
class InternalBucketS3Service extends AbstractS3Service {

  private var _claim : Claim

  internal construct(claim : Claim) {
    super(Configuration.S3InternalBucket)
    _claim = claim
  }
  // no more constructors, only methods ...
```

And I am getting this error:

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Exception in constructor: testGeneralS3ServicesCompare (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor141.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at ru.tinkoff.util.s3.S3TestServiceImplComparisonTest.getRealS3(S3TestServiceImplComparisonTest.gs:59)
    at ru.tinkoff.util.s3.S3TestServiceImplComparisonTest.<init>(S3TestServiceImplComparisonTest.gs:25)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Can you say more about what you want to do with the class?  Maybe there is something else you could do besides a private constructor.

Comment: @grambo25 Its actually good question, i whant to get mock S3 impl and reals S3 impl and write test to compare each other, to ensure they work identically.  Seems like i can manualy instantinate them using Configuration (app properties), instead of using static fabric (which all production code uses to obtain s3 impl depending on app env). But the question is still unanswered - is there a way to do so via reflection?

Answer (score 0):

There is another way how to create instance:

```
var typeInfo = InternalBucketS3Service.TypeInfo
var ctor = typeInfo.Constructors.first().Constructor
return ctor.newInstance({_testClaim}) as S3Service
```

But seems like it works only for `private` constructors. In this case i cant use it, need `internal`.

Am just gonna make constructor `public` and add `@Deprecated` to it to mark "for tests only".
Please comment if it is actually possible to create `internal` object in Gosu via reflection.